# Spectral Measures: Property

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a spectral measure:
$$E:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Can you give me a hint for:
$$E(A)E(B)=E(A\cap B)$$

So far for disjoints I checked:
$$A\cap B=\varnothing:\quad E(A)E(B)=\mathbb{0}$$

Comment: That's normally part of the definition of a spectral measure. What properties are you using for the definition?

Comment: @T.A.E.: Countable additivity and $E(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: That's not enough to make a spectral measure. Either you need $E(A)E(B)=E(A\cap B)$ or something equivalent such as your condition, along with $E(S)^{\star}=E(S)$. Then $E(S)^{2}=E(S)$ follows. That way you have mutually orthogonal range spaces for mutually disjoint sets. $S\mapsto \|E(S)x\|^{2}=(E(S)x,x)$ becomes a positive measure for a spectral measure.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Ah right I forgot: Also $E(A)$ being orthogonal projections for every $A\in\Sigma(\Omega)$.

Comment: And that's what gives you a generalized 'sum of squares' representation that can replace discrete expansions. BTW, on your other question, consider $E(S)f=\chi_{S}f$ on $L^{2}[0,1]$, this is why $\|E[0,t]-E[0,t']\|_{\mathcal{B}(H)}=1$ for all $0 \le t < t' < 1$. About the only thing you can approximate as a class of functions in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ topology using simple functions are continuous functions. Normally you work in the strong operator topology because that reduces to ordinary measure theory $\mu_{x}(S)=\|E(S)x\|^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the partitions
$$
A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B),
$$
$$
B=(B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B).
$$
Also, check out the excellent book by Konrad Schmüdgen for these types of elementary things.

Answer (score 1):

Just an elaboration of user161825's answer.

The spectral measure maps disjoint Borel subsets to projections with orthogonal images.

Therefore the projectors $E(A\backslash B)$, $E(A \cap B)$ and $E(B\backslash A)$ have zero pairwise products.

We have $E(A) = E(A\backslash B) + E(A \cap B)$ and $E(B) = E(B\backslash A) + E(A\cap B)$. Now multiply.